# Magento 2 : how to change order status processing to complete using Rest Api

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, order-status

Any option to update order status processing to complete in Magento 2 using Rest API.

Comment: You should create shipment throught API. The status will automatically change to complete.

Comment: Depending on whether you actually want to actually create a shipment or not, through Magento's API, this SO post shows another way and after trying it out, it works fine. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/315169/how-to-change-order-status-using-api-in-magento-2-3-5

Answer (score 1):

For changing order status processing to complete You need to call following API.

**Endpoint**

```
POST <host>/rest/<store_code>/V1/order/3/ship
```

where 3 is the order id.

**Headers**

```
Content-Type application/json

Authorization Bearer <administrator token>
```

You will get Shipment ID in resonse and status of order will changed to completed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SalesShipOrder](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#!/salesShipOrderV1)

`POST https://{host}/index.php/rest/V1/orders/{orderId}/ship` with the payload described at the link above for each item (product) within the order and when all have been "shipped", the order will be automatically changed to "complete"