# How to Change Order Status using Api in magento 2.3.5

Tags: module, rest-api, order-status, soap-api-v1, magento2.3.5-p1

I want to develop new module for changing order status using Api in magento 2.3.5 so can anyone have idea then please share with me. I want to create order status and change it using Api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Integromat for automatic change order status.
But if I do this API call than I recieve  `400: Request method is invalid.` I tried to use different methods like PATCH, PUT and still get 400.

My connection is functional, beacause other actions like Find orders is functional. But dont know why this api calls doesnt work(any custom API calls).

URL: /rest//V1/orders/

Header:
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer auth.token

Body:

```
{
    "entity": {
        "entity_id": xxxxx,
        "state": "processing",
        "status": "prijata_platba"
    }
}
```

Could you help me with this? Thank you

Comment: Thank You for your solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the rest webservice: http://yoursite.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders

On the body you just have to pass:

```
{
    "entity": 
    {
        "entity_id": your order id, 
        "state":  your state,
        "status": your status
    }
}
```

Don't forget to also include in the http header the following fields:

Content-Type: application/json

Authorization: Bearer Your authentication token

Any more help or explanation needed feel free to ask ;)

try this on postman, it's a lot easier to test and debug !

Comment: I want to develop api for this thing

Comment: What do you mean by developing API? You want to make a C# function to call the Webservice?

Comment: yes i want to C# function to call the webservice

Comment: But which key prevails, the `status` or `state`? Because when I provide the `state` key it won't accept it, but will return a 200 response if it only has the `status` one. So I guess the former one is not required. Is that correct?

Comment: Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this params. It is working.

```
{
    "entity": {
        "entity_id": 1,
        "state":"processing",
        "status": "processing"
    }
}
```

Check mapping in `sales_order_status_state`.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Hi, I want to develop api for that

Comment: Thank you for your solution.